# Server 2012 R2 VSS freezing and causing DFSR and Win Backups to fail

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs-r, vss

Symptom is that approx once a week DFSR (Distributed File System Replication) stops replicating and Windows Backup (wbengine.exe) stops responding. When I analyse their wait chains they're waiting on dfsrs.exe Thread: 4664 and Thread: 4680. dfsrs.exe is waiting on Thread: 4664.

I kill dfsrs.exe and wbengine starts responding. The logs say The backup failed as the creation of a shadow copy has timed out.

Restart dfsrs.exe and we're back in business.

This issue occurs on two new Server 2012 R2 machines (fully updated) with a DFS share to each other. Disabling windows backup on a machine seems to stop it from causing the issue (even though we have other software which creates multiple daily volume shadow copies). Both servers have very little non-microsoft software on them.

I took [dump files](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0Eji2L5qDMdbG0zUTJmMkp4YU0&usp=sharing) of the processes in their stuck state, but I guess VSSVC.dmp is going to be the important one. I don't know how to use WinDbg well, but here's the results I got:

```
0:000> !analyze -hang
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

Probably caused by : dfsrs.exe ( dfsrs!RunTaskCallback+17 )

Followup: MachineOwner
-------------------------------------
0:000> !dml_proc
DbgId  PID    Image file name
0      8c8    C:\Windows\System32\dfsrs.exe
0:000> !dml_proc 0x0
DbgId  PID    Image file name
0      8c8    C:\Windows\System32\dfsrs.exe

Browse module list

Threads:
    DbgId  TID    Name (if available)
    0      8cc    "<No name>"
    1      8e8    "<No name>"
    2      1a70   "<No name>"
    3      1a94   "<No name>"
    4      1af0   "<No name>"
    5      306c   "<No name>"
    6      5d4    "<No name>"
    7      2648   "<No name>"
    8      2654   "<No name>"
    9      204c   "<No name>"
    a      2cd0   "<No name>"
    b      304c   "<No name>"
    c      784    "<No name>"
    d      eec    "<No name>"
    e      3220   "<No name>"
    f      298c   "<No name>"
    10     1238   "<No name>"
    11     2b80   "<No name>"
    12     1248   "<No name>"
    13     3464   "<No name>"
    14     2cf0   "<No name>"
    15     31ac   "<No name>"
    16     3100   "<No name>"
    17     308c   "<No name>"
    18     2a74   "<No name>"
    19     18e0   "<No name>"
-------------------
0:000> ~[0x10]s;kM
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa:
00007ffc`27e606fa c3              ret
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 0000008e`4af1c348 00007ffc`25111118 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
01 0000008e`4af1c350 00007ff7`0540754f KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x94
02 0000008e`4af1c3f0 00007ff7`0537d78c dfsrs!Task::ShutDown+0x283
03 0000008e`4af1c490 00007ff7`053e0656 dfsrs!UpdateDistributionTask::RemoveUpdateTask+0x2c
04 0000008e`4af1c540 00007ff7`053b845c dfsrs!UpdateManager::FinalizeUpdateManager+0x152
05 0000008e`4af1c5d0 00007ff7`053ab007 dfsrs!InConnection::InConnectionContentSetContext::FinalizeInConnectionContentSetContext+0x2e4
06 0000008e`4af1c740 00007ff7`053752e2 dfsrs!InConnection::DeleteContentSetFromInConnection+0x2a3
07 0000008e`4af1c870 00007ff7`0534f1b4 dfsrs!ReplicaSetManager::DeleteContentSetFromReplicaSetManager+0x1e2
08 0000008e`4af1c950 00007ff7`05338e89 dfsrs!ContentSetManager::InternalFinalizeContentSetManager+0x310
09 0000008e`4af1cbe0 00007ff7`053362c5 dfsrs!VolumeManager::FinalizeVolumeManager+0x265
0a 0000008e`4af1ccd0 00007ff7`05323b1a dfsrs!VolumeManager::ShutdownVolume+0x265
0b 0000008e`4af1ce20 00007ff7`05227034 dfsrs!FrsReplicator::FinalizeReplicator+0x182
0c 0000008e`4af1cef0 00007ff7`05239c0f dfsrs!FrsService::InternalShutdown+0x1f4
0d 0000008e`4af1d030 00007ffc`23896e83 dfsrs!VssWriter::OnPrepareSnapshot+0x12f
0e 0000008e`4af1d0a0 00007ffc`2389d145 vssapi!CVssWriterImpl::OnPrepareSnapshotGuard+0x2b
0f 0000008e`4af1d0d0 00007ffc`2389c470 vssapi!CVssWriterImpl::PrepareForSnapshotInternal+0xc71
10 0000008e`4af1e150 00007ffc`270e20f3 vssapi!CVssWriterImpl::PrepareForSnapshot+0x50
11 0000008e`4af1e1a0 00007ffc`270e6fad rpcrt4!Invoke+0x73
12 0000008e`4af1e200 00007ffc`2757d58a rpcrt4!NdrStubCall2+0x35e
13 0000008e`4af1e870 00007ffc`272522b3 combase!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke+0xa0
14 0000008e`4af1e8b0 00007ffc`275786ad oleaut32!CUnivStubWrapper::Invoke+0x53
15 0000008e`4af1e900 00007ffc`27404f5a combase!SyncStubInvoke+0x205
16 (Inline Function) --------`-------- combase!StubInvoke+0xc0
17 0000008e`4af1eaa0 00007ffc`2757951f combase!CCtxComChnl::ContextInvoke+0x27a
18 (Inline Function) --------`-------- combase!DefaultInvokeInApartment+0x51
19 0000008e`4af1ecb0 00007ffc`27578fb0 combase!AppInvoke+0x1af
1a 0000008e`4af1eda0 00007ffc`27579b35 combase!ComInvokeWithLockAndIPID+0x676
1b 0000008e`4af1efe0 00007ffc`270e2467 combase!ThreadInvoke+0x48a
1c 0000008e`4af1f0b0 00007ffc`270e22c0 rpcrt4!DispatchToStubInCNoAvrf+0x33
1d 0000008e`4af1f100 00007ffc`270eaa88 rpcrt4!RPC_INTERFACE::DispatchToStubWorker+0x190
1e 0000008e`4af1f200 00007ffc`270e2d26 rpcrt4!LRPC_SCALL::DispatchRequest+0x4c9
1f 0000008e`4af1f310 00007ffc`270e2b78 rpcrt4!LRPC_SCALL::HandleRequest+0x291
20 0000008e`4af1f3c0 00007ffc`270e195d rpcrt4!LRPC_SASSOCIATION::HandleRequest+0x238
21 0000008e`4af1f450 00007ffc`270e175e rpcrt4!LRPC_ADDRESS::ProcessIO+0x444
22 0000008e`4af1f590 00007ffc`27e0af00 rpcrt4!LrpcIoComplete+0x144
23 0000008e`4af1f630 00007ffc`27e09238 ntdll!TppAlpcpExecuteCallback+0x210
24 0000008e`4af1f6a0 00007ffc`254d13d2 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x888
25 0000008e`4af1fa80 00007ffc`27de54e4 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
26 0000008e`4af1fab0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

Any ideas where to go from here? I didn't think to run process explorer while the service was frozen, but it'll freeze again next week if we want to try then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, problem ended up being backup software (Syncovery) which had a memory leak and was causing VSS to get stuck even when the software itself completed its job. An update seems to have solved the issue.